# heights on ordered/unordered lists not being returned

Tags: jquery

Does jquery handle ordered lists height? I'm getting NULL returned.

js

```
  var highestCol = $('ol.mostrecent').height();
  console.log(highestCol);
```

html

```
    <ol class="mostpopular">
    <li class="heading"><span class="item"></span><span class='desc'>Most Popular Topics</span></li>
    <li class="first rank1 alt1"><span class='desc'><a href='/link/portal/8202/8390/Article/46/How-do-I-view-my-To-Do-List-items' class=contentLinks >How do I view my To Do List (items)?</a></span></li>
    <li class="rank2 alt2"><span class='desc'><a href='/link/portal/8202/8390/Article/99/Do-I-have-to-complete-a-FAFSA-each-year' class=contentLinks >Do I have to complete a FAFSA each year?</a></span></li>
    <li class="rank3 alt1"><span class='desc'><a href='/link/portal/8202/8390/Article/55/Find-or-Reset-Your-Password' class=contentLinks >Find or Reset Your Password </a></span></li>
    <li class="rank4 alt2"><span class='desc'><a href='/link/portal/8202/8390/Article/219/Can-I-appeal-my-Financial-Aid-Denied-status-What-is-the-process' class=contentLinks >Can I appeal my Financial Aid Denied status?  What is the process?</a></span></li>
    <li class="rank5 alt1"><span class='desc'><a href='/link/portal/8202/8390/Article/104/Grants-Available-at-NOVA' class=contentLinks >Grants Available at NOVA!</a></span></li>
  </ol>
  <ol class="mostrecent">
   <li class="heading"><span class="desc">Most Recent Topics</span></li>
    <li class="first alt1"><span class='item'>9/15/2011</span><span class='desc'><a href="/link/portal/8202/8390/Article/232/What-does-NOVA-consider-a-full-time-or-a-part-time-student" class=contentLinks >What does NOVA consider a full-time or a part-time student?</a></span></li>
    <li class="alt2"><span class='item'>9/15/2011</span><span class='desc'><a href="/link/portal/8202/8390/Article/228/Information-regarding-Veterans-Benefits" class=contentLinks >Information regarding Veterans Benefits</a></span></li>
    <li class="alt1"><span class='item'>9/15/2011</span><span class='desc'><a href="/link/portal/8202/8390/Article/227/What-is-the-status-of-my-special-circumstances-request-My-financial-situation-has-not-changed" class=contentLinks >What is the status of my special circumstances request?  My financial situation has not changed.</a></span></li>
    <li class="alt2"><span class='item'>9/15/2011</span><span class='desc'><a href="/link/portal/8202/8390/Article/226/The-income-used-on-my-FAFSA-has-greatly-changed-from-that-tax-year-to-this-Is-there-anything-I-can-do" class=contentLinks >The income used on my FAFSA has greatly changed from that tax year to this.  Is there anything I can do?</a></span></li>
    <li class="alt1"><span class='item'>9/15/2011</span><span class='desc'><a href="/link/portal/8202/8390/Article/225/If-I-receive-a-scholarship-s-can-I-still-get-financial-aid-funding" class=contentLinks >If I receive a scholarship(s) can I still get financial aid funding?</a></span></li>
  </ol>
```

Comment: Are you sure that it selects something with your selector?

Comment: You're aware you're selecting a list with a class of `mostrecent` but your list of the class `mostpopular`.

Comment: Can you check it here:  still getting null
http://www.nvcc.edu/home/ssuh/faid/newindex.htm

Answer (score 0):

Your code on that page looks like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    if (!$.trim($('h1').html()).length) {
        $('h1').hide();
    };
});

var highestCol = $("ol.mostrecent").height();
console.log(highestCol)
console.log("here");
```

The code that's measuring the height is outside the `(document).ready` block -- you're trying to compute its height before the DOM has been rendered. This should work:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    if (!$.trim($('h1').html()).length) {
        $('h1').hide();
    };

    var highestCol = $("ol.mostrecent").height();
    console.log(highestCol)
    console.log("here");
});
```

Comment: No reason to. Happens to all of us, more often than we'd ever admit.